# Android data binding not working with View 'android:tag' property

Tags: android, data-binding

Trying to use the new Android Data Binding in my project, but I'm getting an error when trying to set the 'android:tag' property to some custom variable.

My menu_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="menuItem"
            type="com.example.MenuItem" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:tag="@{menuItem}"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imageResource="@{menuItem.itemType.drawableId}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displayName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{menuItem.itemType.displayNameId}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

My MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem {

    public final ItemType itemType;

    public MenuItem(ItemType itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

}
```

Part of the genetated MenyItemBinding.java:

```
public MenuItemBinding(View root) {
        super(root, 0);
        final Object[] bindings = mapBindings(root, 3, sIncludes, sViewsWithIds);
        this.displayName = (android.widget.TextView) bindings[2];
        this.displayName.setTag(null);
        this.icon = (android.widget.ImageView) bindings[1];
        this.icon.setTag(null);
        this.mboundView0 = (android.widget.LinearLayout) bindings[0];
        this.mboundView0.setTag(root.getResources().getString(com.myApp.R.string.@{menuItem}));
        setRootTag(root);
        invalidateAll();
    }
```

And the error is in the generated class, when trying to set the Tag of the bound view.

Any ideas how to get around this? Preferably, not to use a custom LinearLayout to support this.

Comment: Can you print the LogCat ? I never set a tag directly in xml, didn't even know it was possible. But here if you try to set a MenuItem as a tag, I guess that Android complains because it can't find an empty constructor for MenuItem.

Comment: It's a compile-time error. See part of the generated class above. More specific, the error is on ' this.mboundView0.setTag(root.getResources().getString(com.myApp.R.string.@{menuItem}));' . Regarding the empty constructor - I'm using the menuItem for TextView & ImageView as well and there is no complaint there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a bug. We haven't tried data binding tags, mostly because tags are special.

When targeting devices pre-ICS, Android data binding takes over the tag of the outermost element of the layout. This tag is used for mostly for binding lifecycle and is used by `DataBindingUtil.findBinding()` and `DataBindingUtil.getBinding()`.

So, since data binding isn't working on tags, the only work-around is to not supply a tag to your LinearLayout or supply a fixed tag or resource string. If you are targeting ICS and above, it is valid to reassign the tag after binding the layout:

```
MenuItemBinding binding = MenuItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
binding.getRoot().setTag(menuItem);
```

You can also create a BindingAdapter for a new attribute:

```
@BindingAdapter("specialTag")
public static void setSpecialTag(View view, Object value) {
    view.setTag(value);
}
```

and then use it in your layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:specialTag="@{menuItem}"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"/>
```

This will allow you to use `findViewByTag()` and all of the other things you expect.

However, this will NOT work if you target Honeycomb and earlier devices. There is no getting around that. You may be tempted to do something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("specialTag")
public static void setSpecialTag(View view, Object value) {
    view.setTag(R.id.app_tag, value);
}
```

You won't be able to use `findViewByTag` with that approach, but it will store whatever value you want when you use your view. **But** the reason we don't use ID'd tags with Honeycomb and earlier is that there is a **memory leak** when using ID'd tags, so don't do it.

I hope this helps. I'll file a bug internally to support data bound android:tags.

Comment: There's one thing I couldn't figure out from the documentation - you mentioned it here as well. Where do you place the 'setSpecialTag' method? I was under the impression that a custom LinearLayout is needed for a new attribute with binding.

Comment: The @BindingAdapter annotation is what lets the data binding framework find the method, so these static methods can be anywhere in your code. We recommend having special classes associated with such methods. In this case, you could simply use "app:tag" attribute and it would call setTag automatically because "tag" matches the setTag method -- you wouldn't need any BindingAdapter.

Comment: @GeorgeMount `"you could simply use "app:tag" attribute and it would call setTag automatically "`. Well, I've tried: `app:tag='@{1}'`. The shit hits the fun when you call getTag() in your code. Guess what? It gives you ColorStateList. ColorStateList, Carl! The BindingAdapter approach works well, thanks.

Comment: That is a bug! Thanks for catching it.

Comment: This is a problem with automatic converters that will be fixed in the next release. You can work around it with app:tag='@{(Integer)1}'

Comment: I wonder how does it know where the `@BindingAdapter` method is located? You don't import the static class in the layout, do you. Does this utils class have to be located in the same package as the ViewModel, so it gets found by reflection?

Comment: The processing is done as part of the compilation stage as an annotation processor. It gives the advantage of knowing much more about types used in expressions than reflection does. The particular package does not matter, nor does the class.